# Move diagonally from keypress detection - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to move around a box with arrow keys, like this (simplified):

```
if( Key Pressed = Left Arrow ) {
     move box to left
}
if( Key Pressed = Up Arrow ) {
     move box up
}
if( Key Pressed = Right Arrow ) {
     move box to right
}
```

Here is the actual code:

```js
var left = parseInt(document.getElementById("swag").style.left); 
var topSwag = parseInt(document.getElementById("swag").style.top); 

window.addEventListener("keydown", steerAround, false);

function steerAround(a) {
    if (a.keyCode == "37")  {
      // left arrow key
        left--; 
        document.getElementById("swag").style.left = left + "px"; 
      
    }
    if (a.keyCode == "38") {
        // up arrow key
        topSwag--; 
        document.getElementById("swag").style.top = topSwag + "px"; 
    }
    if (a.keyCode == "39") {
         // right arrow key
         left++; 
         document.getElementById("swag").style.left = left + "px"; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="swag" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#99CCCC">
```

This works almost fine, the box is moving! However, it can only move in one direction at a time! Not both to the left and up for example. How can I fix this?

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't prevent multiple near-simultaneous actions. Show the rest of the function.

Comment: A single keyboard event is only going to tell you about one key, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Use a joystick instead of the keyboard!  (This reminds me of playing games on the family's PC AT clone)

Comment: Do you have the actual code to show us instead of the pseudo-code? It might help us solve the problem.

Comment: More code, and actual code, is up now! (edited question)

Comment: Anyone else envisioning the OP trying to move a cardboard box around using the power of JavaScript, or is that just me?

Comment: @Andy Actual lol, lol :') Isn't that how it works? You just write `id="box"` on the box with a pen, and then the script handles the rest!

Comment: @Pointy Edited question, better? :)

Comment: @isherwood Does the code from the snippet prevent multiple near-simultaneous actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key presses only happen one at a time. You can't get a key press event for more than one key. Even if you press two keys as close in time as you can, one will be detected before the other and you get two separate events.

To handle multiple keys you need to look at the `keydown` and `keyup` events, and keep track of which keys are pressed. Then at a given interval you move the box according to the keys that are currently pressed.

Comment: Thank you. How to I implement the `keydown`, instead of what now seems to be `keypress` or something similar?

Comment: @JakeTheSnake: You actually use `keydown`, but you only move the box at that moment. You should also catch `keyup` and keep track of the up or down state for each key. You can use `setInterval` to run code at an interval that moves the box according to the state for the keys.

Comment: I'm not sure how `keyup` would help me here. Will that take me through the problem of only being able to detect one key at a time? Can I make some sort of different variables that each can detect which keys are being pressed? Thank you.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake: Yes, you would have a variable for each key that you want to track (or an array/object with as many items/properties), and let the `keydown` and `keyup` events change the variable that corresponds to the key. That allows you to check which keys are pressed at any time, not only which key was pressed last at the moment that it happens.

Comment: Everything solved now! Thank you very much, everything gets better with more variables! ;)